# SSO using SAML and Kerberos

Tags: single-sign-on, kerberos, saml

I'm setting up new SSO,the client sends the SSO SAML assertion from OIF to App1(supports SAML & Kerberos).In turn the SSO need to go to App2(supports SAML & Kerberos) and then to App3(Does not support SAML).The flow is Client-App1-App2-App3(in this order).Is there anyway that i can get the SAML auth to App1 and have remaining authentication in Kerberos (i.e.)interpret SAML Auth to Kerberos Auth or is there any other options.Thanks for helping :)

The user should be able to perform SSO from OIF to App3 strictly through App1 and App2.

Comment: Despite some level of experience in SAML and SSO, I really don't understand this. I believe you really need to explain your issue in a more clear way.

Comment: Pardon me for the confusion.let me keep it simple. i am setting up sso between applications A(IDP) & B(SP). I have another application C which does not support SAML instead it supports Kerberos. Can i interpret the SAML (that is received in B) to Kerberos and pass it from B to C. Basically my question is can we interpret the SAML to Kerberos and continue the authentication. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: If you think of issuing a kerberos token from B, I don't think it's easy or even doable at all. It's only a domain controller that can issue valid tokens.

Comment: k. sure. Thank you for helping me on this.